# Getting errors trying to embed tweets using markup (not using api)

Tags: twitter, embed, markup

We are using a cms, where we are storing data about tweets. Since all the data already exists in our db (when people save tweets into it), there is absolutely no reason to use the api to embed tweets, but rather use the twitter supplied js file that loops through all embeds on a page.

However, although the dynamically generated markup from our cms is almost identical and it works with the twitter js file, (check this codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pyyKdL) in our cms i get the error that tweetId is required. However, i am not using the api at all, i just generate the markup with handlebars (since the data is there....).

code from codepen:

```
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-lang="en">
  <p>
    Support your local record shop &amp; pick up the Reapers 7” on <a href="https://twitter.com/recordstoreday">@recordstoreday</a> on 16 April <a href="https://t.co/lgniyAJk3c">https://t.co/lgniyAJk3c</a> <a href="https://t.co/usqrRdW8Bz">pic.twitter.com/usqrRdW8Bz</a>
  </p>— muse (@muse) <a href="https://twitter.com/muse/status/707312257097719810">March 8, 2016</a>
</blockquote>
<script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the twitter script for embedding all markup tweets on a page WILL NOT RUN locally for some reason, all while getting a completely unrelated error (tweetId is not present). Fixed by getting all files to a staging environment (usually the second step, once something works locally).